# How to delete duplicate recursively in Chrome browser's bookmarks?

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks, duplicate

How to delete duplicate recursively in Chrome browser's bookmarks?  I'm guessing because of syncing glitches it end up getting duplicate entries in various places.

Comment: Have you looked in the Chrome Web Store? There's a couple of different extensions for helping manage bookmarks.

Comment: I looked and didn't find any that solves my exact question.

Comment: Not even [Bookmark Sentry](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bdglbbcbmgnimogcmcdenggkpdmihlga)? That's what I use. ([review](http://lifehacker.com/5900229/bookmark-sentry-for-chrome-cleans-up-your-bookmarks-eliminates-bad-links-and-duplicates))